# Dividing the winnings of a game based on the likelihood of either player winning the game.

Tags: probability

I am really struggling in my math 107 class, especially on this project. If someone could point me in the right direction by giving me an example, not solving my project for me, I would be very grateful. Thank you math geniuses.

Two **equally skilled*** players are playing a game of chance by flipping a coin. If the coin comes up heads, Player A gets a point. If the coin comes up tails, Player B gets a point. The first players to 10 points wins. Each player antes $50, so the total pot for the winner is $100. The game is interrupted with player A ahead 8 points to 7. Given the score of the game at that point, how should the $100 be divided so that it reflects each player's likelihood of winning the game? Show your work and explain your answer. It will benefit you to use a tree diagram to organize your thinking on this problem.

*equally skilled indicates that each player started the game with an equal chance of winning.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those problems where you can get an answer fairly easily if you don't get overly hung up on the stopping rule.  That is, suppose the two players agree to imagine tossing the coin *four* more times, even if the winner turns out to be determined after the second or third toss. There are clearly $16$ different results of the four tosses, all equally likely.  What's critical is that there will have been a total of $8+7+4=19$ coin tosses, which means that one player *must* have won at least $10$ of the tosses (since $2\cdot9\lt19$), but not *both* players (since $19\lt2\cdot10$) -- so it remains to determine in how many of the $16$ possibilities does Player A get from $8$ to (or past) $10$, and in how many does Player B get from $7$ to (or past) $10$.  In particular, Player B will need to win at least three of the four tosses, which is to say either exactly three or exactly four.

Answer (score 0):

The question states that you want to figure out how to split the $100 so that it reflects each player's likelihood of winning the game, when A has 8 points and B has 7 points.

Note that the probability that A wins the game is equivalent to the probability that when flipping the coin from there on, you get 2 heads BEFORE you get 3 tails. Do you know how to calculate this probability?

If you find the probability that A wins the game, you can just multiply that by $100 to get the amount of money that B should get if B wins the game. Do you understand why this is?

There is only 1 extra step required from there on to figure out how much money A should get if A wins the game.

Comment: Historical note:  probability theory started developing to answer questions like this.  http://www.glennshafer.com/assets/downloads/articles/article50.pdf

Answer (score 0):

For A, HH, HTH, THH, THTH, TTHH, HTTH are all the possible winning outcomes

pA = .25+.125+.125+.0625+.0625+.0625 = .6875

For B, TTT, TTHT, THTT, HTTT are all the possible winning outcomes

pB = .125+.0625+.0625+.0625 = .3125

Notice pA + pB = .6875 + .3125 = 1

Expected value is the probability of winning times the value of the win

So, For A this is $.6875\cdot100$ = $68.75

For B, this is $.3125\cdot100$ = $31.25